# How to set Trigger in Azure Synapse Pipeline on a specific condition

Tags: azure, etl, azure-synapse, data-transfer, dataverse

I have an azure synapse pipeline with a dataflow which takes datafrom Azure synapse lake database to Azure synapse Dedicated SQL Pool.
Here Azure synapse lake database is in sync with an Azure data lake gen2 storage account(name = datalake2), This datalake2 has many folder each representing a table in the database. For this datalake2 data will automaticaaly synced from dataverse. So when ever a csv file is uploaded or an existing csv file is modified(csv files get modified because the sync is for a monthly basis, so when there is a incoming of data daily until the month completes the existing csv gets updataed)
I want my pipeline to be triggered. I have seen many blogs and documentaion, there I can see only triggers for creation of a new blob, how to do I trigger my pipeline when the existing blob is updated.

I'm ready to provide further details or clarifications for my doubt.

Please anyone let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you explanation your requirement is to trigger the specific pipeline if existing blob is updated in ADLS.

In trigger we have only 2 events **Blob created** and **Blob deleted**:

[image]

If you seclect **Blob created** in trigger it will trigger the pipeline if Blob is created, updated/modified.

I create trigger with above setting and assigned it to pipeline it is triggering pipeline when blob is modified.

**Trigger settings:**

[image]

**Blob modified:**
[image]

**Pipeline triggered:**
[image]